# Solving arrayoutofbounds

Tags: java, arrays

I'm trying to solve an arrayoutofbounds exception
the exact error is:

> Exception in thread "main"
>   java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException:
>   -1
>   Java Result: 1

```
    public static void emptyBox() {
        int , boxRow, boxColumn, i, j;
        emptyBox = 0;
        Row = 0;
        Column = 0;

        for (i = 0; (i < grid.length) && !(1 == emptyBox); i++) {
            for (j = 0; (i < grid[i].length) && !(1 == emptyBox); j++) {
                if (grid[i][j] == 0) {
                    emptyBox = 0;
                    Row = 0;
                    Column = 0;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    I've tried a few attempts at debugging but no dice.
```

Comment: Also, don't use `int` as a `boolean`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
    for (i = 0; (i < grid.length) && !(1 == emptyBoxFound); i++) {
        for (j = 0; (i < grid[i].length) && !(1 == emptyBoxFound); j++) {

---------------------^
```

That should be `j` instead of `i`

I don't know if that's the *only* problem, however...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public static int[][] getSolution(int[][] grid) 
{
    int [][] solution = new int[grid.length];

    if (grid != null)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < grid.length; ++i) 
        {
            grid[i] = new int[grid.length];
            System.arraycopy(grid[i], 0, SolveSudoku.grid[i], 0, grid.length);
        }
        int n = getZeroes();
        solution = getSolution(n);
    }

    return solution;
}
```